# How to state we do not delay?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-request

Time and time again, I've faced situations in which I have to talk about being on time, avoid delay and suchlike. Well, there are many useful verbs which you can use to express your thoughts, however sometimes it becomes tricky, at least for me. In this question, I've aggregated some related questions with each other to avoid asking many very similar questions. All in all, between the following sentences which ones are natural and formal or informal? In each sentence I've highlighted the controversial[!] part by showing it in bold.

> 1. "We should always make sure we never **allow/let any delay** in finishing our homework/project."
> 2. "I never **procrastinate with** my study/project/job/homework"
> 3. "I never **delay/defer** my study/project/job/homework"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatically, you'd be most likely to use...

> I never **put off** doing my homework.

Note that ***put off*** is (very slightly) "informal" by comparison with ***procrastinate***, but mostly that's because the latter is a relatively unusual usage in this context (it might be better described as "facetious" and/or "pseudo-intellectual/pretentious" here).

It's grammatically valid to say you don't ***procrastinate*** with/over/about/regarding/etc. homework, but there's no particular standard as to which preposition works best there. Usually the specific activity being deferred is contextually implied, not explicitly stated and linked to the verb ***procrastinate***.

> I often put off my homework.
>    I often defer my homework.
>    *I often procrastinate my homework.  *(**not valid English**)*
>    I often procrastinate **when it comes to** my homework. *(or* **with/over** *etc.)*

...but...

> I often put off. *(**unlikely English**)*
>    I often defer. *(**unlikely English**)*
>    I often procrastinate. *(normal English - I habitually put off doing many/most things)*

---

In OP's context, including an extra (negated) verb such as ***don't let/allow*** simply implies that the thing counselled against (*procrastination*, here) would be *likely to happen* if you didn't actively make an effort to prevent it (plus of course it implies you have the *ability* to prevent it happening, by making that effort). The syntax of the two verbs is different...

> Don't **allow** any delay in finishing your work
>    Don't **let there be** any delay in finishing your work

...but further details on that should probably be addressed as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks in advance; however, still some questions remained unanswered. First, is the first sentence valid, especially in written/formal English? Second,is "delay" of any use here? By the way, is "put off" formal?

Comment: @mok: I'm not sure what you mean by "formal" there. The phrasal verb ***to put off** = to delay, defer* is certainly not "slang", if that's what you're asking. It's normal English, and it's syntactically simpler in your context than any of your alternatives. So why not use it?

Comment: By "formal" I, simply, mean what you can use in written English, such as a letter to a professor, an academic essay and suchlike.

Comment: @mok: Just use ***put off***. It's "normal" English, whereas ***procrastinate*** is likely to sound pretentious rather than "formal" in your context. But it sounds a bit obsequious to explicitly tell your university professor that you always complete your assignments promptly - why would he expect anything less? Any "informality" attaches to the actual fact of making any such claim, since your professor would expect nothing less anyway.